# Git returns error when started from cron

Tags: command-line, permissions, sudo, cron, git

My ubuntu's `cron` runs a PHP script as `www-data` to collect statistics by executing `git diff --shortstat`, it has been working for a month or so, however, starting 2 days ago, no results were returned.

After some investigation, I managed to replicated the problem in my CLI. If I run `git diff --shortstat`, the output is correct, however, running `sudo -u www-data git diff --shortstat` gives me an error:

```
warning: Not a git repository. Use --no-index to compare two paths outside a working tree
...
```

I did `strace` for both commands and found the difference below. For whatever reason, the command that failed decided not to read into `.git/commondir`

```
## Not working, geteuid() = 33 due to running `www-data`

newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake/.git/commondir", 0x7fffe58445a0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake/.git/objects", X_OK) = 0
access("/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake/.git/refs", X_OK) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0770, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 33
access("/etc/gitconfig", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/.config/git/config", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/.gitconfig", R_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/etc/gitconfig", R_OK)          = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/.config/git/config", R_OK) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/var/www/.gitconfig", R_OK)     = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/usr/share/locale/locale.alias", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0644, st_size=2996, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "# Locale name alias data base.\n#"..., 4096) = 2996
read(3, "", 4096)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0


## Working, geteuid() = 0 due to running as `root`

newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake/.git/commondir", 0x7ffde3edb890, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
access("/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake/.git/objects", X_OK) = 0
access("/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake/.git/refs", X_OK) = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, "/media/sf_www/stage/package-repo/packages/bilogic/pmake", {st_mode=S_IFDIR|0770, st_size=4096, ...}, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = 0
geteuid()                               = 0
newfstatat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/commondir", 0x7ffde3edb9a0, AT_SYMLINK_NOFOLLOW) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
openat(AT_FDCWD, ".git/config", O_RDONLY) = 3
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0770, st_size=285, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
newfstatat(3, "", {st_mode=S_IFREG|0770, st_size=285, ...}, AT_EMPTY_PATH) = 0
read(3, "[core]\n\trepositoryformatversion "..., 8192) = 285
read(3, "", 8192)                       = 0
close(3)                                = 0
```

For further context, these git repos are located on a VirtualBox shared folder. Its owner and group are `root:vboxsf`, and `www-data` is a member of the `vboxsf` group. I do not recall touching any permissions on the system, so it is puzzling why it worked in the past.

I also did some googling which suggested modifying `sudoers.d`, but did not help, it was still `Not a git repository`. Any idea what might be the cause of this issue?

Comment: Hello. What version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: It is `Ubuntu 21.10`

Comment: I did `strace` for both commands and found the difference here https://www.toptal.com/developers/hastebin/coxufecozi.apache .

For whatever reason, the command that failed decided not to read into `.git/commondir`